# Windows 7 computer won't boot and recovery doesn't work

Tags: windows-7, boot, system-restore, dell-inspiron

My Dell Inspiron computer doesn't boot to Windows 7, and when I try system recovery to restore it to previous points it still doesn't work. I tried F12 and performed a total check in which only my battery reported problems. Is there anything else that I can do?

Comment: Is it possible to boot the laptop if you completely remove the battery and plug in the laptop's power adapter? If it boots this way, this indicates that you need to replace the battery.

Comment: Tried it now, doesn't help. I get error 0x80070002

Comment: I tried what you said another time and to a different date of recovery and it worked. Thanks a whole whole lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is it possible to boot the laptop if you completely remove the battery and plug in the laptop's power adapter? If it boots this way, this indicates that you need to replace the battery.

You receive a "0x80070002" error code when some files in the Windows Update are missing, even though the update is downloaded and extracted successfully. To fix this problem, use System Restore to restore back to a restore point before when you downloaded the update.

If you have a bootable system, you can also fix this problem using the [Windows Update Troubleshooter for Windows Update error "0x80070002"](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/910336).